# Print JSON Errors in OL

Tags: php, javascript, json, list

Me again.

I have some errors generated by a PHP created as follows:

```
if (strlen($event_name) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter an event name</li>";}
if (strlen($venue_name) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter a venue name</li>";}
if (strlen($event_date) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter an event date - if not please write TBC</li>";}
if (strlen($address_l1) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter an address</li>";}
if (strlen($postcode) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter a postcode</li>";}
if (strlen($country) < 1){ echo $result['error'] = "<li>You must enter a country</li>";}
```

Then at the end i've got:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

To print these errors to my OL I've got this:

```
$('#errorbox').html(result.error);
```

However, nothing comes of it.... as in it doesn't appear.

EDIT:
This is the function called after completeion of the AJAX:

```
}, function(result) {
        if (result.success == true) {
            $('#errorbox').html(result);
        } else if (result.success == false) {
            $('#errorbox').html("Not working dude!");
        }
    }, 'json');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is `result.error` variable in your javascript? Can you give more of your code or URL to your test page?

Comment: It's all handled using an AJAX request - form data is sent to the PHP file, which generates the errors in the way shown above. Then I want to send them into the OL with ID #errorbox

Comment: still, can you give more of your code or test page?

Comment: added the function ran after the AJAX if that helps

Comment: Why are you echo-ing out the values already at the point where you put them into the array? (And you should _append_ new messages to the array – right now you are overwriting the previous one each time.)

Comment: I don't know - point, I can get rid of that. Any ideas on how to get JS to put them into my OL though?

Comment: How does your html look like? I don't see any <ol id="errorbox">

Comment: Hm... What are you trying to achieve with $('#errorbox').html(result.error); ? If you create a div with the ID errorbox. Is there any difference?

Comment: `<ol id="errorbox" name="errorbox" style="padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 5px;">
</ol>`

Comment: I'll try the DIV thing now... two secs

Comment: Doesn't write to the div either... strange...

Comment: Does $('#errorbox').html('TEST TEST'); write anything?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem - I didn't decare weather it was successful... $result['success'] = true;

Comment: Aha I was thinkg of that to right now, but I'm glad you found the solution! :-)

Comment: Hate stupid things like that - thanks very much for your help. You guys are always great save me many a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overwriting any error with the next one. To avoid that, concatenate the messages:

```
$result['error'] = '';
if (strlen($event_name) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an event name</li>";}
if (strlen($venue_name) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a venue name</li>";}
if (strlen($event_date) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an event date - if not please write TBC</li>";}
if (strlen($address_l1) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an address</li>";}
if (strlen($postcode) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a postcode</li>";}
if (strlen($country) < 1){ $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a country</li>";}
```

Also ensure that the HTML contains an `ul` or `ol` div with the id `errorbox`, and that jQuery is loaded properly.

Comment: Got that outputting the errors correctly in the response found in the developers console however its still not putting it in the OL
`$('#errorbox').html(result.error);` Thats the code i'm using. I have an OL with that ID too :S

Answer (score -1):

You probably wanted to use `+=`, not `=`, the latter overwrites the previous values. You also want to drop the `echo` statements in your string of `if`s. You original code had a  lot of cruft at the top; leftovers from echoing the various `<li>`s.

```
$result['error']="";
if (strlen($event_name) < 1) { $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an event name</li>";}
if (strlen($venue_name) < 1) { $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a venue name</li>";}
if (strlen($event_date) < 1) { $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an event date - if not please write TBC</li>";}
if (strlen($address_l1) < 1) { $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter an address</li>";}
if (strlen($postcode) < 1) { $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a postcode</li>";}
if (strlen($country) < 1) {  $result['error'] .= "<li>You must enter a country</li>";}
```

Now, a GET request to the PHP page should work.

Comment: don't use += if it's not intended for calculation. For concatenation use .=

Comment: Yeah - using the += gave me an output of 0.